# Expected Singleton error trying to domain using company id in ir.rule

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

Hi I want to filter my kanban view using company id but I want my super admin to not be affected by that domain here's what i have tried so far

```
<record id="sample_ir_rule_by_company" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Sample</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_my_model"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('company_id','in',[user.company_ids.id])]</field>
        </record>
```

my problem is I'm getting a `ValueError: <class 'ValueError'>: "Expected singleton: res.company(2, 1)" while evaluating`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `ids` instead?

```xml
<field name="domain_force">[('company_id','in',user.company_ids.ids)]</field>
```

Comment: There should be no square brackets around `user.company_ids.ids` since it return list.